# Apertando a tecla backspace, apagar os campos inputs anteriores

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

O código abaixo faz com que o usuário ao digitar em um determinado campo input, ele pula para o outro campo automaticamente:

```
<form class="form-inline">
 <div align="center">    
  <div class="form-group">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" style="width: 70px" maxlength="1" id="campo1" value="" onkeyup="if(this.value.length >= 1) { campo2.focus(); }">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" style="width: 70px" maxlength="1" id="campo2" value="" onkeyup="if(this.value.length >= 1) { campo3.focus(); }">
  </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" style="width: 70px" maxlength="1" id="campo3" value="" onkeyup="if(this.value.length >= 1) { campo4.focus(); }">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" id="campo7" class="btn btn-default">Acessar</button>
 </div> 
</form>
```

Até aqui tudo certo, mas como eu faria para caso o usuário quisesse apagar os campos anteriores apertando a tecla Backspace?

Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho mais simples fazer toda a lógica diretamente no javascript, construindo todas as funções de `onkeyup` simultaneamente através de um `for`.

```js
//apanhar todos os inputs
let inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".form-inline input");

//ou especificando cada um individualmente
//let inputs = [
//  document.getElementById("campo1"), 
//  document.getElementById("campo2"), 
//  document.getElementById("campo3") ];

for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i){
  inputs[i].onkeyup=function(evento){ //construir o onkey para cada um

    if (evento.key == "Backspace"){ //se for backspace estamos a apagar
      if (i > 0 && this.value.length == 0){ //se não for o 1º e se tiver vazio
        inputs[i-1].focus();
      }
    }
    else if ((i+1) < inputs.length && this.value.length >= 1){ //se não for o ultimo e tiver 1 caracter
      inputs[i+1].focus();
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form class="form-inline">
 <div align="center">    
  <div class="form-group">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" style="width: 70px" maxlength="1" id="campo1" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" style="width: 70px" maxlength="1" id="campo2" value="">
  </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" style="width: 70px" maxlength="1" id="campo3" value="">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" id="campo7" class="btn btn-default">Acessar</button>
 </div> 
</form>
```

Comment: Perfeito Isac. Funcionou!! Obrigado!